# How to insert script tag in head of DOM before it is fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So I am using Electron framework to build an app to load a page and inject my own scripts into it. However, `module` is defined in the global scope and `jQuery` script doesn't see the `window` object because of this

```
if ( typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object" ) {
  // set jQuery in `module`
} else {
  // set jQuery in `window`
}
```

This happens because node-integration is turned on which I want for my injected scripts to run. The problem, as a result, is client side scripts don't work correctly and I see errors like

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
custom.min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
homeOffer.min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
main.js:48 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

If I set `window.module = undefined` before any scripts on the client page runs, then it works fine.

I want to modify the DOM by inserting a script tag which will set `module` as `undefined` before any script runs.

I have a handle on the `document` object and I tried the below

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.innerHTML = "console.log('hello from script'); window.module = undefined;";
    document.head.insertBefore(s, document.head.childNodes[0]);
    console.log('dom loaded');
});
```

However, the problem is the event `DOMContentLoaded` if fired when the DOM has been parsed and all scripts have run so it doesn't serve the purpose.

My question is it possible to run my script tag before any of the scripts runs on the client page?

Answer (score 2):

try:

1. create script file like /script1.js
2. add using this lines of script:

   var jq = document.createElement('script');

   jq.src = "http://www.example.com/script1.js";

   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);

   jQuery.noConflict();

like i add jquery script:

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
// ... give time for script to load, then type (or see below for non wait option)
jQuery.noConflict();
```